# IF and ELSE IF statement is not Working in the MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a query below and i am using IF statement but it is not working .

```
 "SELECT * FROM chat,user WHERE 
IF(chat.seller_id='".$user_id."') THEN user.id=chat.buyer_id  
ELSE IF(chat.buyer_id='".$user_id."') THEN user.id=chat.seller_id"
```

Comment: what's the feed or the error message you got

Comment: Not showing anything .No Error showing

Comment: I think you're missing a join...

Comment: In addition, what's supposed to happen when `$user_id` isn't a `seller_id` or `buyer_id`? If it's undefined, might just want a lone 'else'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this :

```
SELECT * FROM chat,user WHERE user.id = CASE 
 WHEN chat.seller_id='".$user_id."' THEN chat.buyer_id
 WHEN chat.buyer_id='".$user_id."' THEN chat.seller_id
 ELSE user.id='something'
 END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using CASE instead:

```
SELECT * FROM chat,user WHERE 
CASE 
    WHEN chat.seller_id='".$user_id."' THEN user.id=chat.buyer_id
    WHEN chat.buyer_id='".$user_id."' THEN user.id=chat.seller_id
    ELSE user.id='something'
END
```

The else is in case you have any user id that is not a seller or buyer

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this functionally the same as:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM chat c,user u
WHERE (c.seller_id = u.id AND c.buyer_id = ".$user_id.")
 OR (c.buyer_id = u.id AND c.seller_id = ".$user_id.")"
```

Comment: `WHERE c.seller_id = u.id AND c.buyer_id = u.id` would mean the user was both buyer and seller, ie they sold to themselves.

Comment: Though to be honest, the CASE stmt seems more logical.

Answer (score 0):

The logic of your query could also be accomplished with a `UNION`:

```
"
SELECT  *
FROM    chat
JOIN    user
ON      user.id         = chat.buyer_id
WHERE   chat.seller_id  = '".$user_id."'

UNION

SELECT  *
FROM    chat
JOIN    user
ON      user.id         = chat.seller_id
WHERE   chat.buyer_id   = '".$user_id."'
";
```

You should test `UNION` vs `CASE` to see which is faster. Be aware that even if your `CASE` query is valid, you might still get errors testing it in older versions of phpMyAdmin as the parser had issues with `CASE` statements.

If you just want a list of other users a particular `$user_id` has bought or sold from, you might want to consider just querying `user.*` or even just specific `user` columns. The `SELECT *` on both tables leads me to think you want to pull chat history for `$user_id`, but you should also be aware that the logic you have here could grab chats of users that have bought from or sold to `$user_id` but are not necessarily with `$user_id`. Here is an example table:

```
chat_id     buyer_id    seller_id
1           4           6
2           2           6
3           4           9
4           6           4
5           1           4
6           6           5
7           9           2
8           2           4
```

If `seller = 4`, then `buyer_id = [1,2,6] => chat_id [2,4,5,6,8]`

If `buyer = 4`, then `seller_id = [6,9] => chat_id [1,2,3]`

Your results would include `[1,2,3,4,5,6,8]` even though user 4 was only a part of `[1,3,4,5,8]`

If you only want chats for `$user_id`, then you could use something like

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    chat c
JOIN    user u
ON      (
            c.seller_id = u.id 
    OR      c.buyer_id  = u.id
)
WHERE   u.id    = $user_id
```

Also, since you are string concatenating your queries, PLEASE read up and learn to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and parameterized queries to protect yourself from SQL injection attacks.